# Is it possible to implement a "Smaller Numbers than Current" using a single LINQ query?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq

Was doing this problem https://leetcode.com/problems/how-many-numbers-are-smaller-than-the-current-number/submissions/

> Input: nums = [8,1,2,2,3]
>
> Output: [4,0,1,1,3]
>
> Explanation:  For
> nums[0]=8 there exist four smaller numbers than it (1, 2, 2 and 3).
> For nums[1]=1 does not exist any smaller number than it. For nums[2]=2
> there exist one smaller number than it (1).  For nums[3]=2 there exist
> one smaller number than it (1).  For nums[4]=3 there exist three
> smaller numbers than it (1, 2 and 2).

as LINQ-y as possible and came up with a solution which is only half LINQ :(

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] SmallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums) {
        
        var groups = nums
            .Select((val, index) => new { index, val })
            .GroupBy(x => x.val)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
            .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.index).ToArray());
            
        var arr = new int[nums.Length];
        
        int numSmaller = 0;
        
        foreach (var indices in groups)
        {
            foreach (var index in indices)
            {
                arr[index] = numSmaller;
            }
            
            numSmaller += indices.Length;
        }
        
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Is anyone here clever enough to help me figure out a way to LINQ-ify the second half of the solution? Preferably O(n log n) as code I have.

Answer (score 2):

I hope I understood your question. You could do the following.

```
public int[] SmallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums)
{
    return nums.Select(x=> nums.Count(c=> c<x)).ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I'm too slow :) like 10 seconds too slow.

Comment: Ah, but can it be done O(n*log(n)) like mine instead of O(n^2) like yours?

Answer (score 2):

Though I don't think using one LINQ is a good idea here, it is possible to get rid of the `foreach` you have like this, assuming approximate *nlog(n)* is required:

```
nums.Select((num, index) => new { num, index })
        // order number
        .OrderBy(x => x.num)
        // select number with their original index in nums and 
        // their order in the ordered collection
        .Select((x, order) => new { x.num, x.index, order })
        // Group the result by number
        .GroupBy(x => x.num)
        // Consolidate order in the ordered collection by selecting the minimum
        // possible order
        .Select(g => new
        {
            numWithOrder = g.Select(_ => new
            {
                num = _,
                minOrder = g.First().order
            })
        })
        // Flatten the collection
        .SelectMany(g => g.numWithOrder)
        // There should be minOrder number of results in the original collection
        // are smaller than the number
        .Select(x => new { x.num.index, result = x.minOrder })
        // Restore as per original index
        .OrderBy(x => x.index)
        // Select final result
        .Select(x => x.result)
```

As you might have seen, LINQ kills the readability of the code.

Comment: you might wanna read the other answers. I'm not  sure this is any shorter than the one in the question!

Comment: @Damilola This is what I meant LINQ is not a good idea here. I read answers from others, they are shorter but O(n^2) which is less efficient than the OP's version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. It uses the [`Scan`](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Ix.NET/Source/System.Interactive/System/Linq/Operators/Scan.cs) extension method from the [System.Interactive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Interactive/) package, for counting by accumulation the numbers that are smaller than the numbers of the current group.

```
public int[] SmallerNumbersThanCurrent(int[] nums)
{
    return nums
        .Select((x, i) => (Item: x, Index: i))
        .GroupBy(x => x.Item, x => x.Index)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .Scan(seed: (Indices: Enumerable.Empty<int>(), Counter: 0),
            accumulator: (acc, x) => (x, acc.Counter + acc.Indices.Count()))
        .SelectMany(acc => acc.Indices,
            (acc, element) => (Index: element, CountOfSmallerNumbers: acc.Counter))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Index)
        .Select(x => x.CountOfSmallerNumbers)
        .ToArray();
}
```

This solution is arguably even more obscure and unreadable than weichch's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61038885/11178549).

The signature of the `Scan` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TAccumulate> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator);
```

> Generates a sequence of accumulated values by scanning the source sequence and applying an accumulator function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int[] SmallerNumbersThanCurrentShorter(int[] nums)
{
  return (from x in nums select (from y in nums where y < x select y).Count()).ToArray();
}
```

just do this!!

Comment: Completely pointless - this is O(n^2) and identical to earlier posted answer (just using `from ...` instead of LINQ methods). Some explanation why you believe this is better/useful could help.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, sorry guess I was slow!! (20 hours slow). 